# Handlebars display JSON map

Tags: handlebars.js

I need to iterate over a JSON map like so:

```
{{#each myMap}}
console.log("key: " + {{@key}} + ", this: " + {{this}});
{{/each}}
```

`myMap` is a string that looks like this: `{"26":"UPS - Standard","21":"In-Night"}`

It seems like 'each' doesn't iterate over anything at all. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Provided as stated that `myMap` is a string you can't iterate over that. You would have to parse that to a javascript object.

Something like this:

```
var myObjMap = JSON.parse(myMap);

{{#each myObjMap}}
    console.log("key: " + {{@key}} + ", this: " + {{this}});
{{/each}}
```

Also note that only properties that return true from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty will be iterated.